# Using Subquery in having clause using alias

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a Mysql Query where

Where i have a table as like below(Sample data)

```
Employee_id Months Salary
  1         10      200
  2         20      300
  3         30      400
```

Now i wanted to find the Number of Employees who are having the  Maximum total salary
(Total salary =month * salary)

So i have my query like this

Subquery:

```
((select max(mon_sal.mc) as max_mc from (
  select months*salary as mc from employee group by employee_id) as mon_sal)
as max_mon_sal)
```

//To find the Maximum of Total salary

Now my problem is i need to find the number of persons having the maximum salary,

```
select max_mon_sal.max_mc,name 
from employee group by employee_id 
having salary=max_mon_sal.max_mc from (
    (select max(mon_sal.mc) as max_mc from 
      (select months*salary as mc from employee group by employee_id) as mon_sal)
    as max_mon_sal)
```

Its showing Error.I have problem with using the max_mon_sal alias.Please suggest.

Comment: I removed the incompatible database tags.  Feel free to add the tag for the database you are using.

Comment: tanx @GordonLinoff

Answer (score 5):

You can simply use:

```
select count(*)
from employee
where months * salary = (
  select max(months * salary)
  from employee
);
```

Comment: i hope we can't use aggregate functions in where condition

Comment: It is perfectly ok to use an aggregate function in a subquery

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) no_of_employees
  FROM my_table a 
  JOIN 
     ( SELECT MAX(months*salary) total FROM my_table ) b 
    ON b.total = a.months * a.salary;
```

Answer (score -1):

I don't no sure if this is what are looking for, even the better solution for this case is to use temporary tables:

```
SELECT Employee.employee_id,SUM(MONTHs * salary) 
FROM Employee,
   ( 
      SELECT MAX(total) value FROM (
           SELECT SUM(MONTHs * salary) as total
           FROM Employee
           GROUP BY employee_id
      ) T
   ) D
   GROUP BY Employee.employee_id,D.value
   HAVING SUM(MONTHs * salary)  = D.value
```

Comment: tanx for ur suggestion,but i can't use temporary table because of certain constraints.My problem with this exsisting query is (My subqueries are used to find the Maximum salary ,whereas my main query wants to compare with that maximum salary and to find the count of salaries matching with it.I don't know how to compare this in Having clause using alias  name

Comment: @Ramgopal "certain constraints"?? Care to elaborate?

Comment: @Strawberry its not technical,i am preparing for a programming contest where i can't create a temporary table,just i can't create and delete it

Comment: @Strawberry can you please explain, In having clause ,how to compare a column with subquery alias.

Comment: I'm sorry, what you're using here is subqueries, not temporary tables. Also, you really don't need GROUP BY in the external query. The answer from Slaakso is way cleaner.

Comment: In this case it isn't necessary use group by, true. But if one employee has more than on record row, i'm afraid the Slaakso's solution doesn't works :/